# How to get all values from list inside a dictionary, I need to get title for every item

Tags: python, api, dictionary, flask

How to get all values from list inside a dictionary? I need to get title for every item.

```
{'results': [{'id': 654959, 'title': 'Pasta With Tuna', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654959-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 511728, 'title': 'Pasta Margherita', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/511728-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654812, 'title': 'Pasta and Seafood', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654812-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654857, 'title': 'Pasta On The Border', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654857-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654883, 'title': 'Pasta Vegetable Soup', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654883-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654928, 'title': 'Pasta With Italian Sausage', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654928-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654926, 'title': 'Pasta With Gorgonzola Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654926-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654944, 'title': 'Pasta With Salmon Cream Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654944-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654905, 'title': 'Pasta With Chickpeas and Kale', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654905-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654901, 'title': 'Pasta With Chicken and Broccoli', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654901-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}], 'offset': 0, 'number': 10, 'totalResults': 210}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you are stuck on and what output you want... a list of titles? A new dictionary with id as key and the title as the value?

Comment: To start with .. Did you try a simple for loop? May not be the cleanest looking and/or most efficient but still a start... What have you tried so far?

Comment: i was trying just to get a list of  every 'title'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Get all json objects.
for my_dict in data['results']:
   # Get title.
   print(my_dict["title"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
d = {'results': [{'id': 654959, 'title': 'Pasta With Tuna', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654959-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 511728, 'title': 'Pasta Margherita', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/511728-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654812, 'title': 'Pasta and Seafood', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654812-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654857, 'title': 'Pasta On The Border', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654857-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654883, 'title': 'Pasta Vegetable Soup', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654883-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654928, 'title': 'Pasta With Italian Sausage', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654928-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654926, 'title': 'Pasta With Gorgonzola Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654926-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654944, 'title': 'Pasta With Salmon Cream Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654944-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654905, 'title': 'Pasta With Chickpeas and Kale', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654905-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'},
                 {'id': 654901, 'title': 'Pasta With Chicken and Broccoli', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654901-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}],
 'offset': 0, 'number': 10, 'totalResults': 210}

titles = [i['title'] for i in d['results']]
print(titles)
```

Output:

```
['Pasta With Tuna', 'Pasta Margherita', 'Pasta and Seafood', 'Pasta On The Border', 'Pasta Vegetable Soup', 'Pasta With Italian Sausage', 'Pasta With Gorgonzola Sauce', 'Pasta With Salmon Cream Sauce', 'Pasta With Chickpeas and Kale', 'Pasta With Chicken and Broccoli']
```

Explanation:

1. First, the way a list comprehension works is like this:

`[i for i in d['results']]` returns the same result as `d['results']`.

2. Now, you want the value of the `'title'` key fr each dictionary in the `d['result']` list, so change the `i` to `i['title']`:

`[i['title'] for i in d['results']]`

Comment: great thanks, i was trying:  title = [x for x in response['results'] if x == 'title']

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `results` list with a simple list comprehension:

```py
results_dict = {'results': [{'id': 654959, 'title': 'Pasta With Tuna', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654959-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 511728, 'title': 'Pasta Margherita', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/511728-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654812, 'title': 'Pasta and Seafood', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654812-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654857, 'title': 'Pasta On The Border', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654857-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654883, 'title': 'Pasta Vegetable Soup', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654883-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654928, 'title': 'Pasta With Italian Sausage', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654928-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654926, 'title': 'Pasta With Gorgonzola Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654926-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654944, 'title': 'Pasta With Salmon Cream Sauce', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654944-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654905, 'title': 'Pasta With Chickpeas and Kale', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654905-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}, {'id': 654901, 'title': 'Pasta With Chicken and Broccoli', 'image': 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654901-312x231.jpg', 'imageType': 'jpg'}], 'offset': 0, 'number': 10, 'totalResults': 210}


print([result['title'] for result in results_dict['results']])
```

Comment: great thanks, i was trying:  title = [x for x in response['results'] if x == 'title']